# .NET winforms to Apple Macintosh

Tags: .net, macos

I have a winforms of .NET running in windows OS, my client wants the same to be run on macintosh OS, how do i start on this?

Is there a conversion framework (mono/etc) available to implement this?

Comment: seems like you can now http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Answer (score 1):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) (which is an open source implementation of the .NET 2.0 CLR) is probably what you're looking for.

The last time I tried Mono on a Mac (in July), I wasn't terribly impressed. Well, I was impressed that it worked at all, but it was clear that it was still in an experimental stage.

If your application is pure .NET 2.0, then there's a good chance that they will "work". However, there will probably be a lot of work on your end to make it as useable Mac OS X -- some of the UI stuff doesn't translate well (button sizes, fonts, etc.), and there are other little glitches that you'll encounter. Ultimately it will look very un mac-like.

Also, if your app needs COM (to use an embedded IE or DirectX or something), then it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use VMWare Fusion or Parallels to run your unmodified app on a virtual machine:

http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html or http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/

I've used VMWare to run a .net app with on a Vista virtual machine on a Macbook Pro.

Your next -- and perhaps more difficult option -- is to use Mono -- http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

[See this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1222784.php)

Basically it says "The ROTOR project (a Microsoft sponsored open source version of the .NET
runtime), last I saw, had something in the works for the Mac, but realize
that ROTOR is mostly about the .NET bits and pieces that were submitted as a
standard (as far as I remember, WinForms is not in that category).
Also, if you check out the Mono project http://www.go-mono.com/ there is
someone working on a Mac port, but they are far from being done."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mono project's [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), The Mono Migration Analyzer.  It will help you identify incompatibilities in your .NET code when attempting to migrate to the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) framework.